# Liferay: How to make mailing not transactional

Tags: java, api, email, liferay

I´ve been testing MailService and either using setBccAdresses or setBulkAddresses, if you pass 3 real-looking mails, the first and last real and the middle fictional, it does not send any of three, but if you play any other combination with the real mails, it works perfectly.

How can I avoid this behavior, so if server returns a recipient error, other individual mails are sent normally?

By the way, is there any difference in between setting addresses as setBcc or setBulk?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, it was a JavaMail thing.

Just put property

```
mail.smtp.sendpartial=true
```

on your

```
ConfigPanel > Server: Server Administration > Mail > Manually specify Properties...
```

textArea

I still don't know the difference between setBulkAddress and setBCC though